# the matrix in example is following which non-negative matrices ?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The matrix in below is following which non-negative matrices irreducible, stochastic, and primitive (or ergodic) matrices?
i know it is a stochastic row matrix as row sum =1 but i have no idea about irreducible and
primitive (or ergodic) matrices

```
0   0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25
0   0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25
0   0       0.5     0.25    0.25
0   0       0       0.75    0.25
0   0       0       0       1
```

Comment: All eigenvalues of matrix are in a unit circle? what that mean of unit circle?

Comment: What is your question, exactly? Do you mean: prove that this matrix is nonnegative, irreducible, stochastic and primitive? By nonnegative, what do you mean? That all coefficients are nonnegative?

Comment: According to this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix, this matrix is right stochastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A matrix is irreducible if it is not permutation-similar to a block upper triangular matrix. Your matrix is upper triangular, hence automatically block upper triangular and reducible.

A primitive matrix is a nonnegative, irreducible, aperiodic square matrix. Since your matrix is reducible, it is not primitive.

As your matrix is upper triangular, you may read off its eigenvalues from the diagonal. That is, the eigenvalues are $0,\, 0.25,\, 0.5,\, 0.75$ and $1$.

Comment: thanks for nice explanation! Could i ask what is All eigenvalues of matrix are in a unit circle or not? I mean of unit circle?

Comment: @dogukan Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking, but you may notice that the absolute value of every eigenvalue here is at most one, so all eigenvalues lie inside the unit **disc**. However, since some eigenvalues have moduli strictly less than 1, *not* all of them lie on the unit **circle**.

Comment: be honest i didnt understand what is unit circle even i read many explanations,i understood unit circle is x^2+y^2=1 right? so if eigenvalue are 1 it is unit circle otherwise not .do i understand right?

Comment: @dogukan The context here is eigenvalue, so we are talking about the unit circle on the Argand plane, i.e. the set of complex numbers $C=\{z:|z|=1\}$. If you write $z=x+iy$, where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, you may view $C$ as the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. As its radius is 1, it is called a *unit* circle.

Comment: You said that "if eigenvalue are 1 it is unit circle". This is wrong. The eigenvalue $z=1$ is just a point, not a set of points. It **lies on** the circle, but it's not the unit circle. A complex number $z$ lies on the circle if its modulus is 1, i.e. if $|z|=1$ or equivalently, if $z=e^{i\theta}$ for some real angle $\theta$. For instances, the four numbers $\pm1,\pm i$ all lie on the unit circle.